# Using Bing Maps i Non - Mixed reality mobil app

Tags: android

Anyone here used bing maps in an android app? I have tried the method at

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/sdk-native/getting-started-android/

But keep unable to resolve the credential_key. Tried on the bing maps forum and was not any help as all apear to only be interested in web based applications or mixed reality.

If anyone can point me in the direction where I can get more and good information. I do not want to use google maps

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the Github samples for a reference on how to setup the project, and for sample code that demonstrates some basic scenarios.

[Android samples](https://github.com/microsoft/MapsSDK-Native/tree/master/Android/samples)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but been there and checked out still have the same issues.